is there such thing as a よと suffix?
I am currently trying to translate a song and am kind of struggling. Several of the lines end with "信じているよと". I am very unsure about the purpose of the "よと". The only thing I could think of was the ようとする grammar, but that doesn't make sense. Is this something else entirely? I'm still a beginner.

Context please. There are several possibilities for this よと. Please share the entire lyrics or the song title.

My apologies. The title of the song is "The Fusion" by C-CLAYS. @naruto

Is this not just the usual mild emphatic よ + quotative / adverbial と?
